# Selenium Webdriver automaton in C# unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium

I have to write unit test methods for testing a web application using selenium to automate testing. I am new to selenium and point which I am not understanding is :
1) I have written a unit test method for login page with wait.Until command

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void LoginWithParameters()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        try
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestURLLogin"]);
            var userName = driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName"));
            var passWord = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password"));
            var logOn = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value='Log On']"));
            userName.SendKeys(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"]);
            passWord.SendKeys(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]);
            logOn.Click();

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            var by = By.LinkText("Home");
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(by));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Assert.Fail("Test failed. The exception was:\n {0}", ex.Message.ToString());
        }

        var str = driver.PageSource;

        Assert.IsTrue(str.Contains("Home"));


    }
```

2)after login , I have to fill a form and submit. 
 Now condition is 'only if login test is successful , I have to move to form filling unit test method. if login fails then I don't have to go to form filling unit test method.

As far as I understood about Unit testing, unit test methods are not dependent on other unit test methods. So how to achieve selenium automation with webdirver in C# with these conditions?

Comment: I believe you just right click on your test class code and select `Run Test Methods` and they will run in the order of your methods presented on the page?  Is that what you mean?

Comment: this is not a unit test.  this is an integration test. and yes unit tests are not dependent on other unit tests.

Comment: what you have here are pre-requisites for a test.  so I like to write my integration tests out in Gherkin syntax given-when-then  given I am logged on and i fill out this form with the following data when i submit the form then i should see 'x'

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. One approach is to put your tests in some kind of a suite in your framework, trigger the "prereq" suite, and only run the other tests if the "prereq" passes.